# The exact definition of view in android

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I know about `View` class well. But I found an ambiguity by reading this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). There is in the first line the following sentence:

> A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible
>   for drawing and event handling

The above sentence says that a `View` should have width and height and should be as a rectangle. While we can draw various forms using a `View` class .

Answer (score 0):

> While we can draw various forms using a View class .

That does not change the fact that the `View` itself is rectangular. The fact that you choose to paint a non-rectangular content in the `View` does not change the `View`, any more than having non-rectangular content on a Web page somehow causes your computer monitor to no longer be a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is you can definitely draw various forms using the View class but each of these forms are always bounded by a rectangle having a certain width and height.